Removing latex paint from glass
I made a sign using latex paint on glass. Is there an easy way, with or without solvents, to get rid of the paint? I don’t mind buying new glass, but I’d prefer not to. I have mineral spirits and isopropyl alcohol at home.

Use a razor blade scraper to remove the paint.  This is what is normally used to remove latex paint from window glass when painting window sashes in a house or apartment.  Latex paint comes off fairly easily with the razor scraper.
A razor scraper looks like this:

Image source: Amazon.com

Note that this can damage the glass if one's not careful, or if the glass is uneven (as is the case with old glass).

To prevent damaging the glass, an alternative could be to use a plastic razor blade scraper. Although, I don't know how effective it would be.

Try Elmy's method first: soak the sign in water for 24 hours and see if you can peel the paint off.
If that doesn't work, though, or if parts of the sign are still stuck to the glass, I would suggest removing the paint with acetone rather than isopropyl alcohol. Alcohol does remove latex paint, but rather slowly. It's not the ideal paint remover for latex paint. Acetone removes it much more quickly.
Be sure to wear gloves when you do this. Acetone is harder on your skin than alcohol is.

There are different types of latex paint (with different additives) and most are more water resistant than completely water proof.
As a first step, I would thoroughly soak the sign for 24 hours, either by submerging it in water or by covering it in fabric like an old bed sheet and soaking the fabric. If you're lucky, you can simply peel the paint away from the glass.
If that doesn't work, you should be able to dissolve the paint with isopropyl alcohol and paper towels, but I suspect this will require more effort to get the glass clean again.

If soaking helps and the paint softens, a plastic scraper will probably be very useful
